# EXCEL VS TSQL MODULUS

Tags: excel, t-sql, modulus

I'm working on some code to convert some packed IP addresses out of an existing database.  I have succeeded in creating a solution in Excel, but not getting consistent results with creating a TSQL function.  While I can do it in Excel, I'm stubborn and want to figure this out. I've distilled this down to the following difference between the platforms:

--= MOD(-1062674156,256) = 20

--SELECT -1062674156 % 256 = -236

Excel 2013, SQL Server 2017 Standard

An explanation would be great, a fix would be even better!  BTW the answer I'm getting with Excel is what I'm after (20)